# TypeScript determine type by running compile-time function

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have the following piece of code :

```js
const value = JSON.parse('{"foo": "bar"}');
```

Here `value` has type `any` because of the `JSON.parse` signature.

Considering the `JSON.parse` function only has hard-coded argument(s) and has no side effects, it could be run successfully at compile time.
Can I ask TypeScript to evaluate this function at compile time, so it can provide me strong typing for the `value` variable ?

Comment: I don't think it'd be theoretically impossible, but it's not implemented at the moment, and would require quite a lot of effort to code properly, I think

Answer (score 1):

Someone implemented once a JSON parser in typescript I saw it [here](https://twitter.com/buildsghost/status/1301976526603206657?lang=en).

By taking his implementation of `ParseJson` you can do something like this

```
function parseWithTypes<T extends string>(json: T) {
  return JSON.parse(json) as ParseJson<T>;
}

const value = parseWithTypes('{"foo": "bar"}');
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.0-pr-40336-88&ssl=70&ssc=46&pln=66&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBACghgJwM4QQUQQg9ggPAFSggA9gIA7AEySiWAQEtyBzAPigF4oBvIzHAFxR6AV2gBfKADIo%20AFChIUNHGAB1ABYMySMHADGEXAGVgq6CTJUadRi3Yc5UWvSbMipCtSinzT51AA-LCIKOj8eABEKupaOnqGUMxYwEkUqAz6LnbuihCRrP7OQr5kHlbeAAZQACTcTABmqD5mZOLVAD5QlQA65HWNzaUQ7UUBwTGa2hC6BkbDhQEBJa0QCuDQAIKUlADSECAAanAANmK4ALIQALZY5V40AEoQ%20jiUuLZuADRQcOQgrB%20%20xA92s2W%20UGOZwsnjBfwBnCg-iut2kPCgAG1dlAmFBgQBdIRQsRQcTrJTwZAQABSSCw5AA8gAjABWL2AJlWoO8nxYPxRd0sDygz1eCHevOYP3hDh44gc-kl3JowzGwUpYQw2CiGppdMZrPZSRSaXIGSySryBTGQkmcRmCXmq3YQrBlXEA3ITQQLXMoyWzmCGIFP2G%20LGxWUqim8TmnPMLthVUinu9eIO4hT9S9Q1W-oDgajsWms0M8bIiYqNEqAlTub9lQjAfVoT19OJToTysxgx9HZ%20lTrPuG7XDBYLE2j9tLnYr3cqXyHvrajfH45bVNp9OZbP0HOGP22ewOHcuNywQIOPw7rEWa4DtqnJcd5YgleF7qXI9X94nmKPwKniG6YgNepxiICy4QGOv4PiEVLhNquCVLqW4GruqQIC8EAMAAbhAlBQCIZrEJAe4EcIWAANYUEIdTfnev5CLqiE4MhqH6h2UBYcAIgIGahHESQZFkIRuHgdADSCLU3AMU2SzMa2rF4ChrZoTuRpYYYeEUUJpHshRwDUbRMlyWuikIVqbGqZu%20oaXu3HYTpgkkSJhnGeQdGyXmlSFHk8EoGhmyYHAICvt2kr8ue3bwhi%20KInFCrOEqrreKqSwbpqES4JEHH0sFCChcaqTMOkjAWq4LDCBs1oKUWMYOnGCzzviX4%20U2QbAWGTYWYFnESa%2075ghivaQhJA5tQ2MF-naz5Nc686LtmabfvJ4wBW25AFaFuCzbGZYLD8GIAHSncBHb4ox46PsW%202zm%20LWTSua0ZZiJ1neeYHQvioarNN969agVkqXlW0hSCWk4fhLnCQZhFGTRnmmT5V11SxwPsWp-XQo5vH8bprlw1A4k41JCBeXJ-mg6ewwRZVbCcIq9Pdul63o9luVY%202EnFaa5rglVVpXTdDUzoN87kCIJwnE9Iw-q9GKS9Lv3mP9kZ7Y1B0Lal1ZZqNHaZrL%20Z-hi-ZQWryz1dOL7NTr3QYkb8vrhtQXg4NL1QCL1vzV2duVNwjse4WoP2fuzpB57G3KZjtnczjkPOURhPkfDHkUyj5LQKDBB0zkSUu9j5z4EN3ijc8SBS8AaoijMlfdiNOZ9uNAvMBbwQdj1NcVycqR2%20zSEymtwTl5Xa2A9HnOx%20QXE8XxAlJ7DKdd5XtWW-3bGT31cckrP%20Mub2hVMic0Ajz3BQANxyFf1%20Z1AaGItnADkvCRDRIAAIyREIGKRCTYifz8JWJwfpQFfgcAATF-UBf8ICQNJI-Vgl85ANGInuBg9IoB6CpGobQGh8AbCQDnO2kpWAAAoWT6iEPgAAlDwfwu9yB32MAyAAcsdLBKByH6loXAGg2di6XzJHIV45A6DEx5lwDhEAcHADwQQ0hz9IhSSwFAyITJECRHEI-ahN85BAA)

One caveat that it has is that it will infer the types as constant, meaning that the type `foo` won't be `string` but `'bar'` instead.

Comment: Amazing answer, unfortunately I was looking for something generic (not only for JSON, actually my use case is parsing GraphQL queries).

Comment: I now realize that I could implement a similar parser for my use case. I was looking for a fully automatic solution, but this does the trick.

Comment: Yep just follow that twitter thread it is pure gold, something that may help you: https://github.com/jamiebuilds/the-super-tiny-compiler

Comment: Tried going this way, but the TS type parser has a recursion limit which is blocking me from parsing a big json. If you add a bunch of spaces in the playground example json, you will quickly encounter the error : `Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite.ts(2589) `.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```
interface Foo {
    bar: string;
}

const value = <Foo>JSON.parse('{"foo": "bar"}');
const value1 = JSON.parse('{"foo": "bar"}') as Foo;
```

Comment: No, I don't want to write the `interface` definition myself. BTW the key in your example should be `foo`, not `bar`.